# Rewriting into JSON file using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, file

I used jQuery to read from a json file, but when I try to write it to the same file, it won't work.

Here's the code:

```
$.getJSON(src,function(data){
  var about= data.abouttext;
  var mail= data.mail;
  var phone = data.phone;
  $("#about_ta").val(about);
  $("#mail_ta").val(e);
  $("#phone_ta").val(mp);
  $("#wizard_tabs_edit").show();
  $("#mask_edit").show();
  $("#edit_save").on("click",function() {       
    data.abouttext = $("#about_ta").val();
    data.mail = $("#mail_ta").val();
    data.phone = $("#phone_ta").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: src,
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(response){
        alert("aaa");
      }
    });
    $("#wizard_tabs_edit").hide();
    $("#mask_edit").hide();   
  });
});
```

src is the path to the file (working at the `$.getJSON`), and it's giving me the alert "aaa" when AJAX succeeds.

But still, the JSON file remains the same.

Comment: Unless you are posting to a server backend which can change files such as PHP you're not going to be able to `write` changes to any arbitrary JSON file!

Comment: it's for a school project, I'm trying to read data from a json file (on the localhost with the path as src) and then rewrite it to the json file.
it can only happen using php?

Comment: @Yehazkel writing files is a server task. Language used will depend on server environment. There are numerous ways to store data though that can be retrieved using json

Comment: Javascript cannot modify any files directly, all it can do is send data to another process which makes the changes. The other process can be anything that accepts an Http request like Php, a desktop app with a webserver, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to use php or any other backend coding language that can handle the file manipulation for you. Below is an example if you use php5 so you can have a clue:

```
<?php

// Specify filename
$filename = 'myJsonFile.json';

// Read data transforming them to an array
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);

// Push to the array a new pair
array_push($data, ['key' => 'value']);

// Open file for writing
$file = fopen($filename, 'w');

// Write data as json
fwrite($file, json_encode($data));

// Close file
fclose($file);

?>
```